# Is there something wrong with my float:left in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a flag for a website i'm doing and the design is the parts at the bottom of the flag, they stack when i don't float them (expected) but when i do float them, they shrink to the text inside of the box, How can i fix this? Here's my code:

```css
#flag1{
  max-width:400px;
  max-height:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#mainflag{
    background-color:#BA0500;
    max-width:400px;
    max-height:1000px;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}
#flagdesign1{
    background-color:#BA0500;
    max-width:100px;
    position:relative;
    max-height:50px;
    color:#BA0500;
    margin-top:-21px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flag1">
  <div id="mainflag">
    <h1>Flag</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="flagdesign1">
      <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="flagdesign1">
      <h1>A</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the end, it should look something like these[image: End Result]

Comment: You are using max-width, but the standard width is not defined. Therefore, the div's width is based on the content.

Comment: How can i fix the width with still making it relative to screen size?

Comment: can you include a picture of whatever the end goal is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you could try using `display: table;`.

Also, an ID is supposed to be unique, you should use classes instead.
I also used `span` instead of `h1` for the flag element, as IE might not permit using `display: inline-block;`, depending on the version you're supporting.

```css
#flag1{
  max-width:400px;
  max-height:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#mainflag{
    background-color:#BA0500;
    max-width:400px;
    max-height:1000px;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    color:white;
}

.bottomFlag {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottomFlagElem {
  display: table-cell;
}

.bottomFlagElem.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.bottomFlagElem.left {
  text-align: left;
}
.bottomFlagElem.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.bottomFlagElem span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#BA0500;
  max-width:100px;
  position:relative;
  min-height:30px;
  max-height:50px;
  color:#BA0500;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="flag1">
  <div id="mainflag">
    <h1>Flag</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomFlag">
    <div class="bottomFlagElem left">
      <span>A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomFlagElem center">
      <span>A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomFlagElem right">
      <span>A</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```